# error en evento cellformating c# de un datagridview

Tags: c#, windows-forms, ms-access

hola buenas tardes a todos , veran tengo un problema y ya llevo rato verificando el problema o intentando hacerlo con otro evento pero no llego al resultado deseado, sere breve, tengo una base de datos donde hay una tabla de articulos y ventas tengo una de venta desglose tambien donde se muestra el cliente y que productos compro en esa tabla tengo el campo de existencia lo que quiero hacer es que si el valor de la existencia es igual a cero me pinte esa fila completa de rojo , investigando lo pude lograr hacer con el evento cell formating de datagridview pero el problema aqui es que si yo bajo el scroll hasta abajo me marca el error de "referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto" por que sucede esto? y como lo puedo solucionar? se los agradeceria mucho si me pudieran ayudar , adjunto codigo y algunas imagenes

```
 private void GridPrueba_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridPrueba.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Existencia")
        {
            var Fila = GridPrueba.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            if (Fila.Cells[3].Value.ToString() == "0")
            {
                GridPrueba.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: como pueden ver me pinta las filas de color rojo si la existencia esta en ceros]

[image: aqui si yo sigo dando scroll hasta abajo como en la imagen de arriba me marca ese error]

como pueden observar si , se logra pintar las filas con registros donde su existencia sea igual a 0 pero al dar scroll mas abajo me marca la excepcion

Comment: Por qué pones el 0 como string, no es mejor como entero?

Comment: muchas gracias si tenias razon lo que hice fue convertir en el if(convert.toint32(Fila.Cells[3].Value) == 0) y me funciono  y simplemente no poner el cero como un string , ahora no se si esa sea la forma mas eficaz pero me funciono muchas gracias

Answer (score -2):

Por qué tienes el 0 como string y no como entero. Cambia el 0 de string que tienes y lo pones como entero.

```
 private void GridPrueba_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridPrueba.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Existencia")
        {
            var Fila = GridPrueba.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            if (Fila.Cells[3].Value == 0)
            {
                GridPrueba.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Fila.Cells[3].Value.ToString() == 0` Esta comprobación fallará, ya que `.ToString()` devuelve una cadena que intentas comparar con el entero `0`. C# no permite esto.